# Plesk hosting for .Net 4.0

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have plesk hosting server and i am hosting website using .Net version 4.0,
    I am getting error "Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."
    I also have ajax toolkit dll in bin folder of my website

Answer (score 0):

Please do one thing install Ajax 4.0 installed on your server through Control panel > Program & Features.

If not so please install it and then restart it or send me your domain link.

I hope this helps.